# css paddings and borders behave differently in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

It looks the way I like in chrome and safari. but it looks very strange in firefox. It appears to be cut off.I wonder if there is better way of archiving the same results as in chrome and safari for this other than use an actual image of square box. Any ideas? Hacks?

http://jsfiddle.net/vf6gh/

```
.square {
    border:1px solid #0C6DBE;
    background-color:#4293D9;
    padding:5px;
}

<img class="square"></img>
```

Comment: No image needed (nor should you use one for this purpose): http://jsfiddle.net/vf6gh/1/

Comment: Yep, that's the correct fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firefox applies some CSS to broken `<img>` tags:

```
img:-moz-broken:before,
input:-moz-broken:before,
img:-moz-user-disabled:before,
input:-moz-user-disabled:before,
img:-moz-loading:before,
input:-moz-loading:before,
applet:-moz-empty-except-children-with-localname(param):-moz-broken:before,
applet:-moz-empty-except-children-with-localname(param):-moz-user-disabled:before {
    content: -moz-alt-content !important;
    unicode-bidi: -moz-isolate;
}
```

If you're really planning to use `<img>` to simply show an square as you want, rethink it. Those tags were not made for this, and Firefox is a proof of this.

**For knowledge:** user-agent CSS marked with `!important` cannot be overriden.